# How to convert a keras model to a tensorflow estimator and export it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-estimator

I am using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

keras_model = keras.models.load_model('.../model_1.h5')
estimator_model = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=keras_model)
estimator_model.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base, serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
File ".../python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 129, in build
raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

The last layer has the shape (None, 2) but it's passed to the function

```
def build(self, input_shape):
  input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
  if input_shape[-1].value is None:
     raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
                   'should be defined. Found `None`.')
```

in *core.py* as (None, None)!

Comment: Can you add the code for your `serving_input_receiver_fn`?